# Limited powershell start-jobs

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, start-job

I curious if you can answer this or point me in the right direction.

I've written a script that tests/monitors urls.  I'm not posting the code ( unless you want me to ) because there is no error in the code.  It works great.  I can even scriptblock run it as part of start job.  The issue I have seems to be that I can not run more than 3 jobs at time.. or they hang.  I'm not sure why this is.  I can run it for a total of 15 urls throttled to 3 and it's great.  If I try to run it on 15 urls with 4 as my run limit, they will hang.. and I can kill one at a time.. until only 3 remain and those will finish.  So it seems that I can only start a total of 3 powershell instances or they hang.  Anyone explain why this is?  All my searches lead me to pages that show how to throttle and it's not really my issue.

---

Watching the processes, each consumes about 25MBs of memory and sits there idle... If I kill one the other 3 will start using cpu and process go up to maybe 30MBs of memory and terminate completed.  System has 8GBs of memory & a quad cord I5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz.  As requested...

```
Param(
$file
)
$testscript =
{
Param(
[string]$url,
#[ValidateSet('InternetExplorer','Chrome','Firefox','Safari','Opera', IgnoreCase = $true)]
[string]$browser="InternetExplorer",
[string]$teststring="Solution Center",
[int]$timeout=20,
[int]$retry
)
$i=0
do {
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::$browser
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url -UserAgent $userAgent -TimeoutSec $timeout
$data.Content
$findit = $data.Content.Contains($teststring)
$i++
If ($findit){
break
}
}
while ($i -lt $retry)

if(!$findit) {
Echo "opcmsg a=PSURLCheck o=NHTSA msg_t='$teststring was not found on $url or $url failed to load'"

}
}
$urls = Import-Csv $file | % {

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $testscript -ArgumentList $_.url, $_.browser, $_.teststring, $_.retry

}
While (@(Get-Job | Where { $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count -ne 0)
{  Write-Host "Processing URLs..."
   Get-Job
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
$Data = ForEach ($Job in (Get-Job)) {
   Receive-Job $Job
   Remove-Job $Job
}
$data | select *
```

---

So I've used new system.net.webclient and I've even tried doing this with [System.Collections.Queue]... but all three methods use Jobs... so it appears.. I can not run more than three start jobs at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is fine? If you're calling separate powershell sessions multiple times memory can be consumed very quickly. Check process monitor for high CPU or memory usage and ensure your blocks are terminating. Or post the code.

Comment: Updated as you requested

Comment: What do you mean by throttle 15 urls with 4 as the limit? I don't see any max thread count controlling in your code. Have you tried a different web request mechanism such as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259251/powershell-script-to-check-the-status-of-a-url

Comment: In this case.. I'm throttling based on input... the $file has x number of urls in it... so 4 urls 4 processes start..and hang, 15 urls...you get the picture... I removed the code that was doing the trottling as I thought it might be the case.  The suggested process doesn't ( at least that I can find ) offer the ability to search the site for specific text.  I do have another option using New-Object Net.Webclient...but I like the way this works....so unless there is something specific to this command that is stopping the program from running more than 3 times.. I don't really want to change it.

Comment: Turns out...not really sure why... this doesn't work when run from the ISE but if I run it in a console window.. no issues