# Checking to see a website is real powershell

Tags: powershell, url, sharepoint

I have a set of URLs and I want to check if they are an actual site. I have tried this code :

```
$Uri = $Site -as [uri]
                                            if($Uri){
                                            write-host $Uri
                                            }
```

but when I put in a site like https://acasdev.sharepoidnt.com/sites/migrations
which isn't a correct site it still outputs it out as valid

Comment: That's because the *uri* is valid, regardless of whether it refers to an actual resource

Comment: that's not a helpful

Comment: While Mathias might not have provided the answer he did explain why your method was not working. That is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually want to test there is a resource at that URL. Below will actually try to load it.

```
try
{ 
    # First we create the request.
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://acasdev.sharepoidnt.com/sites/migrations')   
    # We then get a response from the site.
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

    # We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "It's dead Jim!"
    exit
}

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
    Write-Host "Site is OK!" 
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
} 

# Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
$HTTP_Response.Close()
```

Reference:
[Powershell Script to check the status of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259251/powershell-script-to-check-the-status-of-a-url)