# Having fits getting results from Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

OK. I am new to powershell but this is killing me. The below code never returns either a status code or a status description. I hace even tried it with a try and catch. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/d/c/3dcc9642-d3a0-459c-86fd- 
    128f5a0c3cc5/Windows10Upgrade9252.exe"
    $output = "c:\Temp\upgrade.exe"
    $Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output -ErrorAction Stop
    $StatusCode = $Result.StatusCode
    $StatusDescription = $Result.StatusDescription
    Write-Host "       Download Status Code: " $StatusCode
    Write-Host "Download Status Description: " $StatusDescription
```

Comment: I've already answered this twice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998880/struggling-with-invoke-webrequest-return-value) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000276/how-do-i-get-return-values-from-invoke-webrequest/66001025#66001025), but you then delete the question and even the account under which you posted the same question.. What's the deal here?

Comment: I hate to say this but no. It was never answered. It was danced around, ducked , bobbed and weaved but never answered. Just like this one. Alternate methods were give but the question, as it was asked, was not.

Comment: _never answered_ ?? I'm afraid you still have a lot to learn about `-PassThru` and when to use `-ErrorAction Stop`. Did you even try the code given?

Comment: Code given? Where?????

Comment: If you ever care to scroll down and look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66001025/9898643) **below** your question, you will find that code.

Comment: That isn't code. Nothing about it answers the question.

Comment: Have you read yor **own** comments under [Francesco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66069964/9898643)  There you even doubt if `-PassThru` is the way to go. Please leave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` by default returns the response object.

If you use the `-OutFile` option, response is saved to the given file and the cmdlet doesn't return anything. Thus `$Result` is null and you don't get any status code.

If you want to save the response object **and** save the response into a file, you have to use the `-PassThru` switch. Om this case `$Result` is an object of type `WebResponseObject`.

For the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet the `-PassThru` swicht is only valid when using the `-OutFile` options

See the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#parameters)

---

A Note: the `-PassThru` switch is a common pattern for cmdlet and is usually very well documented

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but it doesn't really answer the question does it? I mean I am trying to figure why the above code doesn't show any responses. Is the code wrong? is the Write-Host wrong?

Comment: I does exactly respond to the question. Did you try it?
If you don't use `-PassThru` you don't get the response back and thus you don't get the `StatusCode`
Anyway I've reworded a bit the answer

Comment: Sorry but all the above does is to tell me to put a -PassThru option. Nowhere does it explain how to get the results. I have googled it until my fingers hurt and the information is just not there. How about going a little further  and show how to capture and display the  results?