# How to check StatusCode of web request and all its dependent subrequests

Tags: powershell

I have local application and I would like to check not only a specific URL, but also all dependent assets requests (css, js, etc). Is there an easy way to do it?
I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259251/powershell-script-to-check-the-status-of-a-url), but it does not answer my question, it checks only the top-level request. My goal is to test that the page is fully loaded and functional, which is not true if any dependent request fails. I do not want to parse the html file and to execute the requests to http resources that I find there. I want to achieve something like a warm-up for the application, so that is why I request the URL several times:

```
for (($i = 0); $i -lt 5; $i++)
{
     $HttpStatusCode = Invoke-webrequest -URI http://localhost:4203/index.html | select statuscode
     if($HttpStatusCode -eq 200)
     {
     break
     }
}
```

Comment: Your if condition should be `$HttpStatusCode.StatusCode -eq 200` I think.

Comment: Or use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty statuscode`

Comment: No, you cannot check all of your resources load unless you use some form of browser driver.